# Is it a good idea to add name of type of artifact being generated into the artifact name?

Tags: maven, osgi

For example if we wanted to get an artifact from maven central, it would be great to know that I was getting an osgi bundle instead of a plain jar

artifactid=myprojectbundle

Answer (score 1):

Not that there is something wrong with that but typically this is not what projects do. In fact there is no "bundle" artifact per se. Any bundle is packaged as "jar". The term "bundle" basically means it has meta information that OSGi make use of.

It may be a bit confusing because of `maven-bundle-plugin` which requires to change the packaging to "bundle". That however is for the sole purpose of replacing the default build flow in maven. At the end it still produces "jar" file. There is no need to do that with `bnd-maven-plugin`.

The pattern that many projects producing artifacts that are used only (or primarily) in OSGi, it to use fully qualified top package names. Some examples are `com.liferay.users.admin.web.jar`, `org.apache.karaf.jdbc.core.jar`, `osgi.enroute.rest.simple.provider.jar`, ...